# Software to create sprites for mobile games

Tags: image-editor, graphic-design

I am developing some Android games by myself. The problem is I am not able to make a good splash screen and sprites for store, high score, help and play icons.

They are not easy to create in Paint. I would like a software which lets me easily create those sprites.

Like the arrowhead drawer in Power Point and various textures and such effects in Inkscape Portable or Photoshop, but I would prefer simpler software which does the job.

Answer (score 3):

## [Aseprite (free and open source)](http://www.aseprite.org/)

Aseprite is a program that I've found. It's an image editor, but it's geared mainly toward sprite creation and animation.

Screenshot from their website:
[image]